# How to use mobx in react-native 0.56 (Babel 7) with Decorators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, mobx

i've upgraded my RN app from 0.55.4 to 0.56 that use Babel 7.

In 0.55.4 to use decorators for MOBX i use "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy" but is not compatible with Babel 7...

react-native ver: 0.56.0
mobx ver: 5.0.3
mobx-react ver: 5.2.3

does anyone have the solution?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

The app works in `DEBUG` with this configuration

***package.json***

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.0.0-beta.47"
    ...
}
```

***.babelrc***

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["react-native"]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

But in `RELEASE` xCode crash with this error:

```
babelHelpers.applyDecoratedDescriptor is not a function.
```

**UPDATE 2, WORKING CONFIG:**

This is my working configuration:

***package.json***

```
...
"devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.47",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.0.0-beta.47",
   "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.47",
   "babel-jest": "23.2.0",
   "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
   "jest": "23.3.0",
   "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
}
...
```

***.babelrc***

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["react-native"]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

Then in the index.js (main app starting file) i need to import the decorators babel libraries:

***index.js***

```
import applyDecoratedDescriptor from '@babel/runtime/helpers/es6/applyDecoratedDescriptor';
import initializerDefineProperty from '@babel/runtime/helpers/es6/initializerDefineProperty';

Object.assign(babelHelpers, {applyDecoratedDescriptor, initializerDefineProperty});

require('./app.js');
```

***app.js***

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import AppName from './app/index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppName);
```

Comment: There is this `@babel/plugin-transform-decorators` package but it does not help either.
What's even weirder with that is, my problem exists only when I build for `Release` config. `Debug` builds work just fine.

Comment: @Hkan i've tried `@babel/plugin-transform-decorators` too but i riceve same errors... Debug and Release too...

Comment: I think I solved this by installing the exact same version of `@babel/plugin-transform-decorators` with `@babel/core`.

Comment: Ok with `@babel/plugin-transform-decorators@7.0.0-beta.47` build working in `Debug` but in `Release` app crash, error on xcode is: `babelHelpers.applyDecoratedDescriptor is not a function.`. 
some advice?

Comment: Me too. Release bug.

Comment: @AlessandroBottamedi Did you resolve??

Comment: @shinriyo i've updated the question with my working configuration...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, i solved all the errors by adding `@babel/runtime`, now the app works in `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` too.

Here the correct configuration:

***package.json***

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.47",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.0.0-beta.47",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.0.0-beta.47",
  "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.47",
  "babel-jest": "23.2.0",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
  "jest": "23.3.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
}
...
```

***.babelrc***

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": true,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

Thanks @Hkan.

Comment: Turns out, I installed `@babel/runtime` as well. It is implicitly the default value of `moduleName` property for `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`. See [`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-runtime.html) for further information.

Comment: Works like a Charm !!

Comment: im getting this error now, `[tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')`

Comment: I removed babel family and yarn add again. 7.0.0-beta.47 is good?

but not good. It doesn't work!

Comment: I having the same error that @FahidMohammad, did you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.0.0-beta.47` and `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.0.0-beta.47`.

*Versions might change for you. I used those versions because `@babel/core` was also at `7.0.0-beta.47`.*

**Current `.babelrc` is:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": true,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i receve another error `Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` can you share your package.json devDependencies?

Comment: Did the steps mentioned and I ran into the same error as @AlessandroBottamedi

Comment: mine @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.0",