# Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions - v 0.56.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, babeljs

I'm facing this issue in react native v-0.56.0. Please Help me out. When i am downgrading to 50 or 49 it's working fine, but on latest version it's giving this error when creating build  !

cmd npm run ios

My babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.3.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212618/how-to-use-mobx-in-react-native-0-56-babel-7-with-decorators) can help you further